# Deriving a partition identity from some given identities

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions

I am trying questions from Apostol Introduction to ANT of Chapter partitions and need help in deducing this identity.

[image]

[image]

Problem is question 6(a)  which will use some information from 2 and 5(b).

Attempt : To use 5(b) I need to change index of summation so I changed $\sum_{-\infty}^{0} +\sum_{1}^{\infty} $ but the problem is as $\sum_{1}^{\infty} x^{m(m+1)} /2 = \sum_{1}^{\infty} x^{(m(m-1) /2 )} x^2 $. Now m=0 in $x^{m(m+1) /2} =1$  and $\sum_{-\infty}^{-1} x^{(m(m+1)/2}
=\sum_{1}^{\infty} x^{(m(m+1) /2}$ so, I get $ (1-x^{2n+2}) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[ 1+x^{2n-1}]$  which is different from what I needed to do.

So, can you please tell how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting the identity in Exercise $2$ into the one in Exercise $5$(b) yields the identity

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{m(m-1)/2}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n)(1-x^{2n})\,.$$

Examining the exponents, we see that

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{m(m-1)/2}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^0x^{m(m-1)/2}\,,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty x^{m(m-1)/2}&=2\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{m(m-1)/2}\\
&=2\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n)(1-x^{2n})\\
&=(1+x^0)\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n)(1-x^{2n})\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^{n-1})(1-x^{2n})\,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am unable to prove $\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{m(m-1)/2}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^0x^{m(m-1)/2}$ , Rest of the proof is clear , can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: @User: If $m\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $m(m-1)=(-m)(-m+1)$, so $$\prod_{m\ge 1}x^{m(m-1)/2}=\prod_{m\ge 1}x^{(-m+1)(-m)/2}=\prod_{k\le 0}x^{k(k-1)/2}\,,$$ where $k=-m+1$.